# Oracle SQL -- selecting specific data from multiple rows into one row

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying to select data across multiple rows into one row. 
For example, with this data set:

```
NAME     THING        DATE
-----   ------       ------
JACK     1            EARLY
JACK     2            LATER
JACK     3            NOW
JANE     1            LATER
JANE     2            EARLY
JANE     3            NOW
```

I want to produce the following result:

```
NAME       THING          DATE
----        ----          -----
JACK        1, 2, 3       NOW
JANE        1, 2, 3       NOW
```

And so, I know i can use the LISTAGG function to combine the "Thing" rows, but my biggest question is how to select across multiple rows to get the "NOW" values in the date field.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: What is the criteria for selecting the NOW value?  Is it always tied to THING = 3?

Comment: ... or the thing with the highest number, for that name?

Comment: I'm looking for something a little bit abstract, as I may have to do something like this across a number of situations; in this example I'm assuming Date is a date type. i'm essentially looking for a way to, for a series of things, aggregate all the things into one row and select the 'now' value across all rows, returning only one record per name.

Comment: But how do you decide which value is 'now' - the highest date, or the date corresponding to the highest thing?

Answer (score 0):

It isn't clear if you want the latest date for any thing (ordering the aggregated things either by date or by their own values):

```
select name,
  listagg(thing, ',') within group (order by date_col) as things,
  max(date_col) as now
from your_table
group by name
order by name;
```

or the date corresponding to the highest value of thing:

```
select name,
  listagg(thing, ',') within group (order by thing) as things,
  max(date_col) keep (dense_rank last order by thing) as now
from your_table
group by name
order by name;
```

As you said those are actually dates, with your sample data with added date values configured slightly differently for two names:

```
NAME      THING DATE_COL  
---- ---------- ----------
JACK          1 2019-01-01
JACK          2 2019-03-15
JACK          3 2019-04-30
JANE          1 2019-02-01
JANE          2 2019-05-03
JANE          3 2019-04-02
```

the first query gets:

```
NAME THINGS          NOW       
---- --------------- ----------
JACK 1,2,3           2019-04-30
JANE 1,3,2           2019-05-03
```

and the second query gets:

```
NAME THINGS          NOW       
---- --------------- ----------
JACK 1,2,3           2019-04-30
JANE 1,2,3           2019-04-02
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=e69d1a725fa4dc96a98408fbcb95c67a)